# Difference between / + and + in C?

Tags: c

I had a question,

What is the difference between / + and just +?

In my program, i had this line of code

```
md_addr_t GSharePC = PC >> (PC_ZERO_BITS/* + (int)log2(Tournament_Counters)*/) & (Tournmanet_GShare_PHT_Entries - 1);
```

however, when I went to uncommented it, I accidentally left the first / in like so

```
md_addr_t GSharePC = PC >> (PC_ZERO_BITS/ + (int)log2(Tournament_Counters)) & (Tournmanet_GShare_PHT_Entries - 1);
```

it was supposed to be just

```
md_addr_t GSharePC = PC >> (PC_ZERO_BITS + (int)log2(Tournament_Counters)) & (Tournmanet_GShare_PHT_Entries - 1);
```

What is the difference between doing / + and / ? does it actually divide then add? and if so waht does it divide by exactly? Any clarity would be appreciated. I'm interested because using /+ actually generated better results for the program I'm running then just + did.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`+` is both a binary operator (addition) and a unary operator (the opposite of negation).

Your second line parses as

```
(PC_ZERO_BITS / (+(int)log2(Tournament_Counters))) & (Tournmanet_GShare_PHT_Entries - 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

In the second case, `+` is used as a **unary positive operator**.

`+` and `-` signs can be used as **binary** or **unary** operators depending on their context and operator precedence.

`-` is for indicate a negative number, and `+` is for indicate a positive number. `+` is used less frequently because an integer literal is **positive** by default. So doing:

```
printf("Hello %d", + 5);
```

Is equivalent to:

```
printf("Hello %d", 5);
```

That's why your code compiles.

Answer (score 3):

Not every language has a unary `+` operator, and in most of them that do, it's a no-op.  Sometimes, though, it will do things like convert a string to a number in much that same was as `"string" + 0` does in some languages. Ruby has an elaborate parser that analyzes whether an end-of-line is or is not really an end-of-statement marker, so a unary `+` can probably act to continue a statement on to another line.

Anything might be possible with operator overloading.

But back to C99, the unary `+` operator does only one thing: *it applies the integer promotions*. Since those would occur anyway if the operand were used in an expression, one imagines that unary + is in C simply for symmetry with unary -.

It's difficult to see this in action because the promotions are so generally applied. *I came up with this:*

```
printf("%zd\n", sizeof( (char) 'x'));
printf("%zd\n", sizeof(+(char) 'x'));
```

which (on my mac) prints

```
1
4
```

Comment: Cool. The 1st is char, the 2nd in int - it's really not obvious.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see it, you didn't remove the comment, which is `/* comment */`.
You only removed the asterisk `*` and left out the forward slash `/`.
So, basically you're dividing now, and the `+` now is (like other answers said) merely unary.

Answer (score 1):

In this:

```
PC_ZERO_BITS/ + (int)log2(Tournament_Counters)
```

+ is a unary + so you could actually remove it.

Answer (score 1):

It is treated as `(PC_ZERO_BITS)/(+ (int)log2(Tournament_Counters))` so you divide instead of +. You might want to read about [operators precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B). If you can explain what "better" means...